# Spotify music is not heard when I start a Skype call

Tags: sound, spotify

When I start a Skype call and I am listening to music in Spotify, I stop hearing the music. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: We need a lot more details. What are you starting the call with?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, click on sound, click on the music button in the spotify field, ready!

[image]